# Envio de e-mail por meio de um botão de notificação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, mailer

Gostaria de saber se você já fizeram ou tem algum exemplo que possa mandar o link para o seguinte problema:

Tenho um projeto que tem o crud de books e um controller User com suas respectivas views.
Fiz o modulo de e-mail normal como o `generate mailer` que se chama loan.

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar um button com um link na view book que ao clicar mande um e-mail solicitando o empréstimo do livro.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Acho que você terá que criar no seu modelo (Models) um método que chamando o método Mailer já criado.

Comment: @augustoppimenta como assim o models, o mailer já foi criado! 
O que eu quero é quando o usuário aperta um botão, envie um e-mail!

Comment: Dá uma olha nesse [link](http://blog.glaucocustodio.com/2012/11/06/enviando-emails-via-stmp-do-gmail-com-action-mailer-do-ruby-on-rails-ex-de-formulario-de-contato-e-model-sem-tabela/). Acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: @augustoppimenta isso aí já foi feito! Tem uma notificação por e-mail quando um usuário é criado!
O que tava querendo é que depois que o usuário logado se quiser apertar um botão de 'loan' de um 'book' o usuário que postou o book possa receber um e-mail com a solicitação!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá. Vou tentar ser o mais breve possível. Primeiro você não especificou se o usuário que vai pedir o livro está logado ou não. Vou supor que ele esteja, mas caso não estivesse você teria que passar algum parâmetro de contato dele. Vou supor também que seu mailer tenha uma ação book_loan_request(user_email, book_id) que recebe o email do usuário que requisitou e o id do livro.

Segue a action:

```
    class BooksController
      def book_loan_request
        LoanMailer.book_loan_request(current_user.email, params[:id]).deliver_now
        redirect_to book_path(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

E a rota:

```
    resources :books do
      member do
        get :book_loan_request
      end
    end
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, me ajudou bastante! 
Já foi resolvido !
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa Adriano é uma ação no Controller que é disparado pelo click do botão através de uma URL.

Exemplo:

No seu controller teria uma action:

```
def send_invite_book
   seu_parametro = params[:seu_parametro]
   SeuMailer.alguma_funcao(seu_parametro).deliver_now

   # Aqui você pode usar redirect, respond_to para html, js, json, etc.
end
```

Na sua rota, vc precisa ter acesso a essa função, ex, no arquivo routes.rb

```
post '/url_que_vc_quer', to: 'seuController#send_invite_book'
```

Pronto, se você colocar essa url na sua view usando os helpers de path por exemplo, você irá chamar a action no controller que irá disparar o e-mail chamando seu Mailer.

Isso está beeeeeem simplificado, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: você tá falando para cria esse method no controller books ou criar um novo controller !?

Comment: pode ser no seu books controller mesmo. e cria uma rota para a action

Comment: Sua rota pode ser melhorada tbm. Pode usar o resources `resources :books do member do post :book_loan_request end end` .. isso se tornaria a url : /books/123/book_loan_request

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma rota específica para essa ação.

No controller, implemente a action que responde a essa rota.

Nessa action, chame o método no seu Mailer que envia o email que deseja